# admin.database is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-admin

Iam using firebase admin but when I use exports like

```
var admin = require('firebase-admin');

var serviceAccount = require('./firebaseconfig.json');

admin.initializeApp({
 credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
 databaseURL: "https://database.firebaseio.com"
});

module.exports = { admin : admin }
```

and used in another file by require like

```
var admin = require('../Firebaseconfig/firebase.js');
console.log(admin.database())
```

then gives error while starting the server
but if iam using admin.database() in the same file then Iam not getting any error.

error snippet:

1. console.log(admin.database())
2. TypeError: admin.database is not a function
   at Object.

Comment: `module.exports = admin`

Comment: thanks Prakash it worked

Answer (score 1):

You exported an object containing `admin`. So you have to use admin.admin.database() :D
Or just export admin. `module.exports = admin`